# ImportError: No module named django even though Django is installed

Tags: python, django

When I write `pip list`, I can see django there. When I write `import django` in python shell, there is no error. But when I write `python manage.py runserver` it gives me the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x105838b18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/manitgupta/virtualenvs/testify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/manitgupta/virtualenvs/testify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/manitgupta/virtualenvs/testify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/manitgupta/virtualenvs/testify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/manitgupta/virtualenvs/testify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/manitgupta/virtualenvs/testify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/manitgupta/virtualenvs/testify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 127, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django
```

Comment: do you have more than one instalation of python?

Comment: yes. is that the issue?

Comment: Also check if the name of your project/app/file is django, if it is then change it.

Comment: @sP_ didn't get you. Are you saying that I shouldn't have any file named django in any of my apps? Well I don't have any.

Comment: @manitg907 yes, I was saying that. Since you have multiple installations of python, make sure you're using the right pip. Like if you're using python3 to run django, install django using pip3.

Comment: Yes use pip3 to install django and it might work

Comment: I'm using python 2.7, so pip install django should have worked.

Comment: Try running `python` from the command line. Then in the interpreter, do an `import django` and see if you get any error.

Comment: @musikreck thats what I wrote in the question, it is not giving any error.

Comment: Try finding out where your Django package is installed and run your script (`python manage.py runserver`) from there. It could be that you've installed Django in another directory

Comment: @manitg907 were you able to fix it? If not can you create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce the error on our system?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution? To reproduce this (by installing [Biostar](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central/tree/django19)): create a virtualenv ; `cd` inside and `source bin/activate` it ; clone `https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central.git` ; fetch and checkout branch `django19` ; `pip install --upgrade -r conf/requirements/base.txt
` ; (optional) `source conf/defaults.env` ; `./biostar.sh init import run` or `python manage.py runserver`